# CSS Issues between browsers when using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have make this design using CSS and it looks great on Chrome.I'm also using bootstrap, and noticed that bootstrap is causing to looks different on FF

This is my CSS. I have my deno on jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/yosusixe/2

Any idea why this happens?

```
         div.bonecard {
                background-color: white;
                margin: 10px;
                width: 340px;
                height: 210px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-left: 2px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
                -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
                -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
                border-radius: 20px;
                border-top-right-radius: 50px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
            }
            div.bonecard:after, div.bonecard:before {
                background-color: white;
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                content:"";
                border: 2px solid black;
                border-right: 2px solid white;
                width: 6px;
                left: -10px;
            }
            div.bonecard:before {
                top: 60px;
                height: 60px;
            }
            div.bonecard:after {
                top: 180px;
                height: 30px;
            }
```

This is an image of how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an unknown reason Firefox is taking box-sizing: border-box (from bootstrap), while Chrome does not. You can add following code to each class:

```
div.bonecard {box-sizing:content-box}
div.bonecard:after, div.bonecard:before {box-sizing:content-box}
```

Now the elements will look the same in both browsers.

Comment: great. Here is the demo showing the same result on both browsers: http://jsbin.com/yosusixe/8

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap uses box-sizing:border-box on all their stuff -- it's global in all elements without exception -- so you don't count borders or padding:

This works in both now:

### http://jsbin.com/yosusixe/4/edit